# What is color matrix code of "Denim blue"color on flutter?

Tags: flutter

this is my code

```
 ColorFiltered(
                          colorFilter: const ColorFilter.matrix([
                            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
                            2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
                            0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
                            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, //
                          ]),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "assets/step1.png",
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                          ),
                        ),
```

output is blue

[image]

I want this blue

[image]

color code
**#1560BD**
What is color matrix for this color code ?

I want like this color  (expecting color)
[image]

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? you want that circle to be denim blue?

Comment: no I want only colofilter  matrix code

Comment: I already coloured the image so my code works perfectly

Comment: what is you original image and what do you expect after applying color matrix?

Comment: I will add that image

Comment: what exactly your problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you, I have refer [this](https://observablehq.com/@pstuffa/hex-code-to-fecolormatrix-filter) or [this](https://www.emexee.com/2022/05/hex-to-color-matrix-converter.html) for ***Hex to ColorFilter.matrix*** conversion

```
ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: const ColorFilter.matrix([
           0.08235294117647059,0,0,0,0, 
           0,0.3764705882352941,0,0,0,  
           0,0,0.7411764705882353,0,0, 
           0,0,0,1,0
        ]),
        child: Image.network(
          'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg',
        ),
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Welcome, Try to upvote my answer.